# Get user profile using Oauth 2.0 from LinkedIn API

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I want to implement "sign up using LinkedIn" functionality ,I followed this document and stuck at point b with this error instead of getting access token. 
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "missing required parameters, includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more then once. : client_id"
}
```

I want to fill user basic information in registration form e.g. firstname,lastname,email etc.
I dont want to use javascript API,and need to go with REST API of linkedIn ,

Comment: Could you share what your request looks like? What are the parameters that you pass?

Comment: to fetch user login prompt of linked in;this will give me code value that will be used to get access token : https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=myclientid&scope=r_basicprofile&state=abc123ha&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/MyApp/

Comment: to get accesss token i used:
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=generatedCode_from_first_redirect_url&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/MyApp/#&client_id=client_id_val&client_secret=client_secret_val

Comment: No, i was talking about your HTTP request that you sent. It is possible that you might have constructed your http request incorrectly which is causing this error.

Comment: not getting you by HTTP request,I had only sent these two requests, 1st request is simple redirect and second one i executed with postman client for testing service using chrome

Comment: i was wondering why it is showing error like this,i was able to fetch access token day before {"expires_in":5184000,"access_token":"my_generate_daccess_token"}

Comment: these are the API endpoints... you would have sent a request like this - http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token
?oauth_nonce=89601180
&oauth_timestamp=1305583298
&oauth_consumer_key=653e7a6ecc1d528c516cc8f92cf98611
&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1
&oauth_version=1.0
&oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com

Answer (score 11):

This return a json file with the user info:
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token=value&format=json

For a specify value:
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(firstName,lastName,picture-url)?oauth2_access_token=value&format=json

Comment: Nice tip. I would just add an example of json result for the full user info call with sample chars:

{"firstName":"Antonio","headline":"CEO at MyCompany srls","id":"BLaaaO5111","lastName":"Smith","siteStandardProfileRequest":{"url":"https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=AAoAZZEudacBj6aIZpZhUBizzH_1KfcxmBxwcl5&authType=name&authToken=AXXX&trk=api*a1111853*s4411103*"}}

Comment: I took 2 days to find this answer! It's unbelievable that LinkedIn does not provide this information in their API documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Please refer the following,

http://www.bigcode.net/2013/08/linkedin-share-api-usage-using-oauth2.html

It has the details on using OAuth2 and accessing one of the api.

The code may be used for authentication. 
Once you are authenticated, you can use the Profile api mentioned here

http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api to get the profile details.